# How do I create a generic interface in Python?

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to create the equivalent of this in Python:

```java
static class Event {}

static class MyEvent extends Event {}

interface Filter<E extends Event> {
    boolean filter(E event);
}

static class MyFilter implements Filter<MyEvent> {
    @Override public boolean filter(MyEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my attempt [(mypy-play)](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=54dca4dc19dbb1ed1b13a81d54621ad2):

```python
from typing import TypeVar, Protocol

class Event:
    pass

class MyEvent(Event):
    pass

E = TypeVar("E", bound=Event)

class Filter(Protocol[E]):
    def filter(self, event: E) -> bool:
        raise NotImplementedError

class MyFilter(Filter):
    def filter(self, event: MyEvent) -> bool:       # should be ok
        raise NotImplementedError

class BadFilter(Filter):
    def filter(self, event: object) -> bool:        # should fail
        raise NotImplementedError
```

...that fails with `main.py:11: error: Invariant type variable 'E' used in protocol where contravariant one is expected`. Unless I'm misunderstanding, Java seems to be fine with an invariant one, and this is my idea as well; I don't want various `Filter`s to be compatible with one another. In any case, slapping `contravariant=True` onto `T` [doesn't work either](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=8e08b0d8806e91884981a1f9a65f36a2). So,

Why the protocol needs a contravariant variable? And, how do I make this Python code type check?

Comment: Your "doesn't work either" link says "Success: no issues found in 1 source file" when I hit "Run".

Comment: Oh, wait, you were expecting `BadFilter` to fail. The contravariance means `BadFilter` is fine. A filter that can filter arbitrary objects can filter events.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica `MyFilter` filters subclasses, and `BadFilter` filters superclasses. surely one of these should be failing?

Answer (score 10):

Protocols don't allow that, because it breaks subtype transitivity. See [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#overriding-inferred-variance-of-protocol-classes).

If you have the following two classes:

```
class A:
    def method(self, arg: int):
        pass

class B(A):
    def method(self, arg: object):
        pass
```

then `B` is a valid subclass of `A`, because `B.method` can accept any arguments `A.method` can. However, if you could introduce the following protocol:

```
T = typing.TypeVar('T')

class Proto(typing.Protocol[T]):
    def method(self, arg: T):
        pass
```

then `A` would satisfy `Proto[int]`, but `B` would not, due to the invariance of `T`.

Comment: i suppose that if following my Java idea, that is if `A` was explicitly implementing the protocol, subclassing it like that would be an error and this issue wouldn't arise. I guess I want to either use something other than `Protocol` or use a contravariant `TypeVar` instead. This is my latest [attempt at the latter](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=eac9c4de2e5d578a6c0b711289c7d262)—looks good?

Comment: @squirrel: Seems fine at first glance. `foo: Filter = BadFilter2()` passes because `Foo` is interpreted as `Foo[Any]`, and `Any` is basically the "don't check me" type. It's sort of like using raw types in Java.

Comment: aha, thanks. any idea why it's interpreted as `Filter[Any]` instead of `Filter[E]` as it was defined? I'm not sure it is like it works in Java as Java needs explicit declaration of interfaces and simply wouldn't allow me making something like `BadFilter2`

Comment: @squirrel Late response, but: type annotations are optional and relatively recent in Python. Any is the default because otherwise typing old code would be prohibitive. Type-checking tools like Mypy generally have options to disable implicit (and even explicit) Any, but they're not enabled by default so that people can adopt these tools gradually.